# Invoking nonstatic methods of a class

Tags: c#

What (if any) is the upside or downside (performance, good coding practice, garbage collection etc.) of invoking a non-static method of a class in the manner below:

```
new ClassA().MethodA(param1, param2);
```

as against the more "traditional" way of

```
ClassA classA = new ClassA();
classA.MethodA(param1, param2);
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does ClassA create any unmanaged resources or implement IDisposable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Coding**
As for coding practice, the second option is better, where the object is stored in a variable first. The reason that makes it better is that you get to name the object according to the context where it's used. For example:

```
var pendingUserForRegistration = new User();
```

---

**Performance**
As for performance, the first option could be slightly better, since it uses the object directly from the stack and skips the storage of the object in a local variable. It can be seen from the IL of the methods:

*IL of first:*

```
.maxstack 8
L_0000: nop 
L_0001: newobj instance void NS.ClassA::.ctor()
L_0006: call instance void MS.ClassA::M()
L_000b: nop 
L_000c: ret
```

*IL of second:*

```
.maxstack 1
.locals init (
    [0] class NS.ClassA c)
L_0000: nop 
L_0001: newobj instance void NS.ClassA::.ctor()
L_0006: stloc.0 
L_0007: ldloc.0 
L_0008: callvirt instance void NS.ClassA::M()
L_000d: nop 
L_000e: ret
```

This is usually a tiny performance overhead, it's hard to find a case where it'll solve a real performance problem.

---

**Bottom line**
Since the maintainability of the code gain here is greater than the performance gain it's preferred to store the object in a variable with meaningful name.

Comment: Thanks Elisha. Excellent detailed answer. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Also, hinted at in @SwDevMan81's comment on the question - if the object you're using is disposable you'd want to put it into a variable so that you can later dispose of it cleanly; doing it the first way leaves the clean up wot the object's finalizer, which may (for example) leave connections open.

Answer (score 3):

It wouldn't make any difference at all. It's just that in this situation a static method would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: I agree, unfortunately my influence does not extend to modifying that class :). Also becomes a little difficult to manage multi-threading

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in the back end. In the CIL it will create a ClassA object, then call the method. Both pieces of code translate to the same CIL, thus there is no performance difference at all.

Answer (score 1):

If your're not going to use ClassA for anything else, than `new ClassA().MethodA(param1, param2);` is OK. Otherwise you should go with the more traditional instantiation `ClassA classA = new ClassA();`

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks a lot for the prompt response.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any difference between them. However, if `ClassA` implements `IDisposable` both are a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. If ClassA implements IDisposable, what are the repurcussions?

Comment: If `ClassA` implements `IDisposable` you should invoke the `Dispose` method when the instance is no longer needed, either manually or through a `using` statement. Failing to do so may cause the code to leak unmanaged resources (depending on what `ClassA` does).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Fredrik. I appreciate the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The two are identical.  In fact, there's a good chance the the compiler will generate identical IL for each.

The traditional method this a advantage in debugging, if you are sure if a problem is in the ctor or in MethodA; or if MethodA alters the object, and you need to inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I use static methods when I don't need the class to "know" anything; I use instance methods when the class needs to be aware of itself and its own state.

More or less.

Answer (score 0):

I find myself asking why you'd want to do this at the calling site. If you can't get around it, it might be better to wrap the `new ClassA().MethodA(a,b)` in a static method to avoid code noise at the call site.

Answer (score 0):

They are identical. The first approach means one fewer lines of code. The second approach is slightly nicer if somebody needs to modify the code to start calling `MethodB`.

Comment: Makes sense on the second point. Probably the compiler resolves both the same way anyways. Thanks for such a prompt response

Answer (score 0):

Your first approach needs to instantiate an instance of ClassA (in addition to loading the class definition into memory if the class was never used so far). The second approach avoids this additional object instantiation and the following garbage collection of the class.

If this happens from time to time and not millions of times, I would not bother. However, it would be a more clean design to implement the method static if you do not need access to any class instance method or property.

There is a slightly different approach used sometimes: Assume ClassA needs an argument in it's constructor that would maybe initialize a private field or a property that would in term be used by your method. In this case, the first approach is a must:

```
new ClassA(param0).MethodA(param1, param2);
```

But - even then, the method could just be redefined to take additional parameters.